# How do I use jQuery's .animate method with min-height?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to use `min-height` with jQuery.animate like this:

```
$insert.animate({ min-height : 52 }, 1000).animate({ opacity : 1 }, 1000);
```

but it breaks the script. If i use `height : 52` it works. Any ideas?

edit: [see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/hh8Q8/1/)

Comment: was min-height set prior to trying to animate it? I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to animate that property.

Comment: i have to insert an element and animate it at a certain height, bu if there is come picture inside that element that can be bigger or smaller, i want the element to automatically resize, with a min-height

Comment: but what is it animating from? Again, was there a previously set value for min-height?

Comment: height: 0 or min-height: 0? I'm not entirely sure you can animate that particular property. To animate the height of a div, it has to animate the height property as well anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping `min-height` in quotes:

```
$insert.animate({ 'min-height' : 52 }, 1000).animate({ opacity : 1 }, 1000);
```

I should add: I'm assuming `$insert` is a pointer to a block element, i.e. `$insert = $('#insert')`, where `#insert` is an HTML element with `display: block`. I tried my solution [in JSFiddle too](http://ttp://jsfiddle.net/hh8Q8/).

Comment: it converts somehow to `height:0px`. looks like it doesn't understand it

Comment: I added some new assumptions to my answer, does your code match that?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/hh8Q8/1/  . it should animate to the `.test` size

Comment: My mistake, I misunderstood what you were saying. So you want the parent (`#insert`) to animate to the child's (`.test`) size?

Comment: oh, i see. I have to change a bit the technique i use to match what u showed me, but it should work fine.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$insert.animate({'min-height':'500px'}, 1000);
```

This is correct syntax using jQuery 1.7